# When using Angular Rails Templates ng-include can't find the template file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

im building a Rails app and use `angular-rails-templates` gem. Im trying to load the template using ng-include and it's not working. Here's my application.js :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require lodash
//= require_tree ../templates
//= require_tree .
```

The template file is located in `assets/templates/person.html`
The index.html.erb file which have ng-include (Only the part that have it) :

```
<li ng-repeat="item in dirList.list | filter:search">
    <ng-include src="'person.html'"></ng-include>
</li>
```

The js file (only the first part) :

```
angular.module('directoryApp', ['templates'])
    .controller('directoryController', function() {

        var dirList = this;

        dirList.toggle = true;
```

What might be the problem? The rest of the app is working! What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to use angular templates inside rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade 'sprockets' gem to '2.x.x' version (e.g. 2.12.3) manually in the Gemfile, if you are using 'angular-rails-templates' 0.2.0 version or earlier because it currently has a dependency on 'sprockets' 2.x.

Besides that, be sure to put

`config.angular_templates.ignore_prefix  = %w(templates/)`

in 'config/application.rb' file.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709334/angular-rails-templates-just-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue, ultimately realized the angular syntax required an element when using the ng-include statement.  The following worked for me.

```html
<li ng-repeat="item in dirList.list | filter:search">
    <div ng-include="'person.html'"></div>
</li>
```