# AngularJS, Rails and ui-router not showing template

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to do [this tutorial](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/) and I'm on the part of `Angular Routing`. And they're using `angular-ui-router` instead of ng-route. So I found a [AngularUI router on github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which gives a bit more info in using it. But I'm not getting the desired result.

I've added the route-ui through bower using `bower install angular-ui-router` in the rootfolder of my project which created all needed files etc.

I've added the needed files in my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

//= require angular
//= require angular-ui-router
//= require angular-animate
//= require angular-rails-templates

//= require angular-app/app
//= require_tree ./angular-app/templates
//= require_tree ./angular-app/modules
//= require_tree ./angular-app/filters
//= require_tree ./angular-app/directives
//= require_tree ./angular-app/models
//= require_tree ./angular-app/services
//= require_tree ./angular-app/controllers
```

When I check the `<head>` I can see that the angular and router files are being loaded. Also my Angular functions are working.

In my angular-app folder I have a modules folder which has a searchModule.coffee.js file with the following content,

```
@app = angular.module('app.movieseat', [ 'ui.router' ]).config([

  '$urlRouterProvider', ($urlRouterProvider) ->
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise '/state1'
    # Now set up the states

  '$stateProvider', ($stateProvider) ->
    $stateProvider.state('state1',
      url: '/state1'
      templateUrl: '../templates/state1.html').state('state1.list',
      url: '/list'
      templateUrl: '../templates/state1.list.html'
      controller: ($scope) ->
        $scope.items = [
          'A'
          'List'
          'Of'
          'Items'
        ]
        return
    )
])
```

The templates folder is also inside the angular-app folder.

My body looks like this,

```
%body{"ng-app" => "app.movieseat"}

  %div{"ui-view" => ""}
  %a{"ui-sref" => "state1"} State 1
  %a{"ui-sref" => "state2"} State 2
```

So I should include the state1.html in the `ui-view` but nothing is happening.

I am including the correct files, but the ui-view isn't doing anything. I'm also not getting a error in my console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had made an mistake while defining config block,

Add both the dependency in function one go.

**Code**

```
@app = angular.module('app.movieseat', [ 'ui.router' ]).config([

  '$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) ->
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise '/state1'
    # Now set up the states

  //'$stateProvider', ($stateProvider) ->//basiacally you don't need this line
    $stateProvider.state('state1',
      url: '/state1'
      templateUrl: '../templates/state1.html').state('state1.list',
      url: '/list'
      templateUrl: '../templates/state1.list.html'
      controller: ($scope) ->
        $scope.items = [
          'A'
          'List'
          'Of'
          'Items'
        ]
        return
    )
])
```

Comment: @PeterBoomsma does it helped?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the angular-ui-router is incompatible with the new Rails sprockets.  To fix this, add this earlier version of sprockets to your gemfile:

`gem 'sprockets', '2.12.3'`

And then run `bundle update sprockets`.

This was answered a few times in other similar questions, like the one below:
[Angular Rails Templates just not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709334/angular-rails-templates-just-not-working)