# Cannot make angular-rails-templates work

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I used to keep my angular templates in public folder but I need to add some ruby in my views, so I'd like to put them in assets/templates using angular-rails-templates. However, and after following [documentation](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates), I can't manage to make it work. Here's my code :

assets/javascript/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= angular/angular.min
//= angular/angular-route.min
//= angular/angular-resource.min
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require_tree ../templates
//= angular/main
//= require_tree .
```

assets/javascript/angular/main.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'templates',
    'ngRoute',
    'articleController',
    'basketService'
    ]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/articles/categories/type', {
    controller: 'categoryTypeCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'articles_view.html'
    })
```

views/layout/articles.html.haml

```
!!! 5
%html{'ng-app' => 'myApp'}
    %head
    %base{:href => '/'}
    %title FilterApp
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = csrf_meta_tags
    %body#articles
        =render "shared/details_header"
        #articles_container.container-fluid
            .row
                %div{'ng-view' => ''}
        =render "shared/footer"
```

I've added `gem 'sprockets', '2.12.3'` to my gemfile as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709334/angular-rails-templates-just-not-working) but still I can't render articles_view.html, only the layout. So does anybody see something I'm missing ? Thanks for your time.