# Rails + AngularJS: How to make"templateUrl" work from the /assets directory

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to load a bootstrap window. The data that will be displayed in the modal window is located in `assets/javascripts/angular/templates/modalView.html.haml`.

I installed these gems for angularjs and bootstrap:

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem 'angularjs-rails'
gem 'angular-ui-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'angular-rails-templates'
```

this is `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require angular
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require_tree ./angular/templates
//= require angular-resource
//= require angular-ui-bootstrap-tpls
//= require_tree .
```

and the JS code handling the modal window:

```
$scope.openModal = function() {
  console.log('here');
  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'modalView.html', // also '/modalView.html' doesn't work
  controller: 'PostsCtrl'
});
```

But when I try to open the modal, I get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/posts/modalView.html 404 (Not Found)
```

Any tips how to properly configure paths without putting the files into the `/public` folder?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Rails Templates just not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709334/angular-rails-templates-just-not-working)

Comment: I already tried that, didn't help.