# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/index.html") with AngularJS and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, angular-ui-router

I am learning AngularJS and how to use it with Rails, so I started following [this](http://angular-rails.com/) book and everything on the Chapter 1 worked perfectly... This includes install the necessary gems, install bower, install dependencies via bower, setup the asset path, etc... even the [Tiniest Angular app ever](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjcS7.png) worked perfectly.

I got the problem while I was following the instructions of Chapter 2.

Supposedly I should see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDuCE.png) when I access to my app, but instead of that I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIxch.png), a blank page...

The full error displayed on the terminal is this

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/index.html"):
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /home/patricio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/patricio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/patricio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /home/patricio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rezeta/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered /home/patricio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rezeta/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /home/patricio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rezeta/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (7.6ms)
  Rendered /home/patricio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rezeta/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /home/patricio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rezeta/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (39.5ms)
  Rendered /home/patricio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rezeta/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered /home/patricio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rezeta/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)
  Rendered /home/patricio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rezeta/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /home/patricio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rezeta/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /home/patricio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rezeta/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (15.3ms)
  Rendered /home/patricio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rezeta/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.2ms)
  Rendered /home/patricio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rezeta/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.3ms)
  Rendered /home/patricio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rezeta/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (29.7ms)
```

I do not understand why this happens and I have not been able to solve this so far.

The only changes I made from Chapter 1 to where I got the problem in Chapter 2 were:

1. Add `gem 'angular-rails-templates'` to the Gemfile.
2. Run `bundle install`.
3. Add `asset 'angular-route'` to the Bowerfile.
4. Run `rake bower:install`.
5. Add `//= require angular-route/angular-route` and `//= require
   angular-rails-templates` to the /assets/javascripts/application.js
   file.

And finally put the following code to their files, as it comes in the book.

**app/views/home/index.html.erb**

```
<div ng-app="receta">
  <div class="view-container">
    <div ng-view class="view-frame animate-view"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app/assets/javascripts/app.coffee**

```
receta = angular.module('receta',[
  'templates',
  'ngRoute',
  'controllers',
])

receta.config([ '$routeProvider',
  ($routeProvider)->
    $routeProvider
      .when('/',
        templateUrl: "index.html"
        controller: 'RecipesController'
      )
])

controllers = angular.module('controllers',[])
controllers.controller("RecipesController", [ '$scope',
  ($scope)->
])
```

**app/assets/javascripts/templates/index.html**

```
<header class="row">
  <h1 class="text-center col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">Find Recipes</h1>
</header>
<section class="row">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <label for="keywords" class="sr-only">Keywords</label>
      <input type="text" autofocus class="form-control" placeholder="Recipe name, e.g. Baked Potato">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Search</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
<hr>
<section class="row">
  <h1 class="text-center h2">Results</h1>
  <section class="well col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h1 class="h3 col-md-6 text-right" style="margin-top: 0"><a href="#">Baked Potato w/ Cheese</a></h1>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <button class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="well col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h1 class="h3 col-md-6 text-right" style="margin-top: 0"><a href="#">Garlic Mashed Potatoes</a></h1>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <button class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="well col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h1 class="h3 col-md-6 text-right" style="margin-top: 0"><a href="#">Potatos Au Gratin</a></h1>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <button class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

[This](https://github.com/oicitrapdraz/rezeta/commit/91fbec410af4efd5139800bc779fa5059dbe8558) is the github repository (with the corresponding commit) of the application I'm trying to do, in case you want to see some other file, I really do not know what other info I should give because I'm new to AngularJS and how to use it in Rails.

EDIT:

**`rake routes`**

```
    Prefix Verb URI Pattern           Controller#Action
home_index GET  /home/index(.:format) home#index
      root GET  /                     home#index
```

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular/angular
//= require angular-route/angular-route
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require_tree ./templates
//= require_tree
```

**Bowerfile**

```
asset 'angular'
asset 'angular-route'
asset 'bootstrap-sass-official'
# vim: ft=ruby
```

Comment: Do you have a route defined for your `root_path` in `config/routes.rb`? E.g. `root :to => 'home#index'`

Comment: @dinjas Yes, I do...

Comment: Have you added `require_tree ./templates` to your application.js?

Comment: @BroiSatse I had not, but I just added `// = require_tree ./templates` and there was no change.

Comment: @cursillosonline - have you added it after `//= require angular-rails-template`?

Comment: @cursillosonline - also, have you added templates to your angular module dependencies?

Comment: the error really looks like a routing error to me. If you run `rake routes`, are there any routes that point to `home#index`?

Comment: @dinjas - This is not routing error. 'rails-angular-templates' should add all the templates to the angular cache - when everything is correct then there should be no request at all.

Comment: I edited the post to add the result of rake routes, and the code from app/assets/javascripts/application.js and Bowerfile.

Comment: @cursillosonline - Sanity check, when you open the page, your browser should load q lot of javascript files. Are there any files from templates folder? (You can check it in developer tools under scripts tab). Actually it has to be there otherwise your angular module would fail to instantiate. Question is, what is in those files: you should see something like `($templateCache.put(important stuff here))`

Comment: @BroiSatse gotcha, my bad :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `gem 'sprockets', '2.12.3` to my Gemfile, running `bundle update` and finally restarting the server by `Ctrl+C` and `rails server` did the trick for me.

The solution was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29705124/angularjs-and-rails-routing-error), but the problem in my case persisted cause I didn't restart the server.